# Regex to Name.Surname

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to filter user login names but keeps getting garbage along. The user names and surnames starts with capital letters. I'm using grep GNU 2.10.

Like **A**lbert.**O**hara

```
[A-Z].*[.][a-zA-Z].*
```

Then the following chars are either space or other punctuation i.e. /;
i think it's missing some code "except punctuation or space".

Getting Albert.Ohara/blahblah or Albert.Ohara blah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to match `First.Last`:

```
\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\.[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\b
```

Use `grep -E` for extended regex support.

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\b          # word boundary
[A-Z]       # match an uppercase letter
[a-zA-Z]*   # match 0 or more of letter
\.          # match a literal DOT
[A-Z]       # match an uppercase letter
[a-zA-Z]*   # match 0 or more of letter
\b          # word boundary
```

Comment: grep -oE "\b[A^C][a-zA-Z]*\.[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\b"
It worked. Thank you!